# Variable in flask within a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have this line in a foor loop in flask and I want to set variable that would be increase each loop by a certain number. So f.e. margin-top is **50, 100, 150**

```
<td style="margin-top:50px;">
```

Can anyone hint me a how to do such a loop, please? Is it possible to do it within this framework? Thanks

```
{% for picture in pictures[item.id]%}
                <td style="margin-top:50px;">
                    <img src="{{url_for('static', filename=picture)}}" style="z-index:0;" />
                </td>
        <!--<div class="image_description">{{ picture.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0] }}</div>-->
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would you go for all this trouble? Just create a class in `css` and add it to each `<td>`.

```
.myclass-with-50-margin-top {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

The result remains the same.

Edit:

```
{{rowCount = 0}}
{% for picture in pictures[item.id]%}

    <td style="margin-top: {{count += 25}}px">
         <img src="{{url_for('static', filename=picture)}}" style="z-index:0;" />
    </td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: So each of them would have different class with different value? I have unknown number of cells. Once the gradiation must be by 50, other time 25. So I think it would find this very handy. Why do you think that this is trouble-making?

Comment: I updated my answer. You got to ask yourself: "When do I need that gradiation to be 25? When do I need it to be 50?" If you need 25 margin-top, just create another class and change the logic in your Python-loop accordingly. Hope this helps

Comment: So maybe I should have explained what I am actually wanting. F.e. I have 5 cells on top of each other. I want to create cascading effect so once has margin 20, other 40, other 60 and the last 80. The step is dynamic depending on how many cells are on the page. So I can't really see any other solution as long as it's created with flask and not javascript.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your needs, you could use loop.index to avoid creating another variable as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
<td style="margin-top:{{loop.index*50}}">
```